# Can't sort array with comparator

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I implemented this method to sort an array of teams that have a lot of attributes
and it sorts depending on if the attributes are equal, it pass to the next one

Here is the class

```
public class Equipo  implements Comparable<Equipo>{

private String nombre;
private int puntos;
private int cantidadPartidosGanados;
private int golesDiferencia;
private int golesAnotados;
private int golesEnContra;
```

and here is the method

```
  public void ordenar() {
    Collections.sort(listaEquiposTorneo, new Comparator<Equipo>() {
        public int compare(Equipo a, Equipo b) {
            if (a.getPuntos() != b.getPuntos()) {
                return a.getPuntos() - b.getPuntos();
            }
            if (a.getCantidadPartidosGanados() != b.getCantidadPartidosGanados()) {
                return a.getCantidadPartidosGanados() - b.getCantidadPartidosGanados();
            }
            if (a.getGolesDiferencia() != b.getGolesDiferencia()) {
                return a.getGolesDiferencia() - b.getGolesDiferencia();
            }
            if (a.getGolesAnotados() != b.getGolesAnotados()) {
                return a.getGolesAnotados() - b.getGolesAnotados();
            }
            if (a.getGolesEnContra() != b.getGolesEnContra()) {
                return a.getGolesEnContra() - b.getGolesEnContra();
            }

            return a.getNombre().compareTo(b.getNombre());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is calling the method ordenar() enough to sort the list?

Answer (score 0):

Sorting only works if the comparison is symmetric. For items A and B:

- if A and B are equal in order, so are B and A (`compare(b,a)==0` implies `compare(a,b)==0`)
- if A is larger than B, then B is smaller than A, and vice versa (`signum(compare(a,b)) = -signum(compare(a,b)))`

If this symmetry is violated (which I suppose is the case in your code), the sorting will fail.

Comment: Looking at the logic, two teams can never be equal unless all their stats are the same and they have the same name. That seems unlikely. Also, the comparison is symmetric (not compare(a, b) = -compare(b, a), but signum(compare(a, b)) = -signum(compare(b, a)), which I believe is what you meant, although in this case the former will also be true).

Comment: You're right, I meant the signum, corrected my answer, thanks.